# List number radius verification

Tags: haskell

I'm in need of your expertise once again, I find myself struggling with Haskell due to my lack of experience. I have a list (inac) and I need to check the numbers in that list so that there are none in a radius of 5 numbers, like for example, I have the number 300 in my list I check to see if there's there number 295 and 305, if there aren't then 300 goes in another list (rInac)

```
dig :: Int -> [Int] 
dig 0 = []
dig n = dig (n `div` 10) ++ [n `mod` 10]

inac :: [Int]
inac = [x | x <- [1..999], x `mod` sum (dig x) == 0]

rInac :: [Int]
rInac = [x | x <- inac, rAux x]

rAux :: Int -> Bool 
rAux n = n `elem` inac
```

Right now I'm only checking that the numbers (n) belong to the list, my problem is, I'm unsure of how to do the 5 radius thing...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think a list is a good datastructure for this, since lookup is inefficient here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem inac and rInac need to be a list, now the checking I'm not sure how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `any` function to determine if a list contains a value that satisfies a certain predicate. For example:

```
any odd [1,2,3,4]   -- True
any odd [2,4]       -- False
```

All you have to do is make a predicate function that would determine if the number lies in a radius of 5:

```
rAux :: Int -> Bool 
rAux n = any isWithinFive inac
    where 
        isWithinFive x = x >= n-5 && x <= n+5
```

However, this will yield you an *empty* `rInac` list. Because every number is within radius 5 of itself, this predicate will hold for every number in the `inac` list. I suspect that what you *really* want is to check for the existence of numbers within 5 from the given number, but excluding the given number itself:

```
rAux :: Int -> Bool 
rAux n = any isWithinFive inac
    where 
        isWithinFive x = x /= n && x >= n-5 && x <= n+5
```

Comment: Hey, so I ran what you wrote there, both ways, and didn't get what I was expecting, I might have explained myself wrong, I have the inac list which has a series of numbers, and from those numbers on inac, I want to check which ones are sorta isolated, meaning, I want to check those from inac that don't have another inac number 5 numbers before and after, and get them to the rInac list. (The inac list has specific numbers and there are supposed to be 30 rInac numbers)

Comment: If you want the list to contain only isolated numbers, then you should include only those that _don't_ have any close neighbors. You can use  the `not` function to negate a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is sorted, of a Bounded type (such as Int), and you are comfortable that its values will never approach the boundaries (about +/- 2^63 on a 64 bit machine) the following code should be fairly intuitive and efficient (i.e., O(n) in constant space if the ghc optimizer is doing its job):

```
gapped :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
gapped g a = map fst $ filter test $ zip a $ zip (minBound:a) (tail a ++ [maxBound])
  where
    test (x, (l, u)) = l+g < x && x < u-g
```

For example, using your other code, `gapped 5 inac` yields:

> [90,126,162,171,180,300,342,351,432,531,540,576,612,660,666,684,690,756,792,810,840,846,864,888,954,960,966,972,990,999]

Is that the answer you were looking for?